# How can I record the date (before beeing modified) in SharePoint?

Tags: date, sharepoint, calculated-columns

This is my first post, I am Dani.

I would like to know how to record a date in another column when this one is modified in SharePoint.

I have a tasks list with some columns, one of them is "Deadline Date" and another one is "Previous Deadline Date", I would like to record the "Deadline Date" when is modified in "Previous Deadline Date". (Not the Last date Modified)

I think this has to be done with a Calculated Column but I do not know how to build it, the logic of the formula should be something like that:

`=IF([Next Deadline Date] "is modified", then Record [Next Deadline Date])`

Any help, explication or  Link to understand how to calculated fields works in this case is very welcome.

I would like to avoid Code due permissions but I accept suggestions too.

Thanks very much!

Comment: You can achieve this goal by using a Event Handler or Worflow, see MSDN for how-to.

Comment: Thanks Max. I asked to install VS in my workstation. Let you know the results then.

Comment: Based on Sharepoint version you can create simple workflow with Sharepoint Designer 2010 or 2013 (Warning you cannot install 2013 for 2010 version) without Visual Studio